# Looping through parsed JSON to find a string match (Caused by: java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException: -1)

Tags: java, android, arrays, json, sorting

I am creating an app where the user puts in a name into an EditText. This text is then used in a loop to see if there are any matches in the parsed JSON data. If there is a match the match will be added to an ArrayList. This array list is then adapted to a listview.

```
private void handleJsonNameResponse() {

    if (mNameArray == null) {
        // TODO: handle error
    } else {
        try {
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> namePosts = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

            HashMap<String , String> namesAndCreatedHash =  new HashMap<String, String>();

            for (int i = 0; i < mNameArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject namePost = mNameArray.getJSONObject(i);
                String name = namePost.getString(KEY_CONTENT);
                name = Html.fromHtml(name).toString();
                String created = namePost.getString(KEY_CREATED_AT);
                created = Html.fromHtml(created).toString();

                if ( name == mName ) {

                    namesAndCreatedHash.put(KEY_CONTENT, name);
                    namesAndCreatedHash.put(KEY_CREATED_AT, created);

                    namePosts.add(namesAndCreatedHash);

                }


            }

            String[] keys = { KEY_CONTENT , KEY_CREATED_AT};
            int[] ids = {android.R.id.text1 , android.R.id.text2};

            SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(NameListActivity.this , namePosts, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2,
                    keys ,ids);
            setListAdapter(adapter);


            }catch(JSONException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
```

I don't see what i'm doing wrong but i keep getting this error  Caused by: java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException: -1

here is the full code

```
public class NameListActivity extends ListActivity {

private String mName;

public static final String TAG = NameListActivity.class.getSimpleName();

private JSONArray mNameArray;

private final String KEY_CONTENT = "content";
private final String KEY_CREATED_AT = "created_at";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_name_list);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    mName = intent.getStringExtra("name");

    if (networkIsON()) {
        GetNameData getNameData = new GetNameData();
        getNameData.execute();
    } else {

    }


}


private void handleJsonNameResponse() {

    if (mNameArray == null) {
        // TODO: handle error
    } else {
        try {
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> namePosts = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

            HashMap<String , String> namesAndCreatedHash =  new HashMap<String, String>();

            for (int i = 0; i < mNameArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject namePost = mNameArray.getJSONObject(i);
                String name = namePost.getString(KEY_CONTENT);
                name = Html.fromHtml(name).toString();
                String created = namePost.getString(KEY_CREATED_AT);
                created = Html.fromHtml(created).toString();

                if ( name == mName ) {

                    namesAndCreatedHash.put(KEY_CONTENT, name);
                    namesAndCreatedHash.put(KEY_CREATED_AT, created);

                    namePosts.add(namesAndCreatedHash);

                }

            }

            String[] keys = { KEY_CONTENT , KEY_CREATED_AT};
            int[] ids = {android.R.id.text1 , android.R.id.text2};

            SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(NameListActivity.this , namePosts, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2,
                    keys ,ids);
            setListAdapter(adapter);


            }catch(JSONException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }


private boolean networkIsON() {
    boolean isOn = false;
    ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = manager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
        isOn = true;
    }
    return isOn;
}


private class GetNameData extends AsyncTask< Object , Void , JSONArray> {

    @Override
    protected JSONArray doInBackground(Object... objects) {
        int responseCode = -1;

        JSONArray jsonResponse =  null;

        try {
            URL nameUrl = new URL("https://fast-lowlands-9315.herokuapp.com/posts.json");
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) nameUrl.openConnection();
            connection.connect();

            responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
            Log.v(TAG , "" + responseCode);

            if (responseCode == 200 ) {

                InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
                Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
                int contentLength = connection.getContentLength();
                char[] charArray = new char[contentLength];
                reader.read(charArray);
                String responseData = new String(charArray);


                jsonResponse = new JSONArray(responseData);

            } else {
                Log.i(TAG , "unsuccessful HTTP response code" + responseCode);
            }

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return jsonResponse;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray result) {

        mNameArray = result;
        handleJsonNameResponse();
    }
}
```

}

this is the error i am getting in my logcat

```
02-08 09:38:15.190  27892-27979/com.androidy.listactivity E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
Process: com.androidy.listactivity, PID: 27892
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
 Caused by: java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException: -1
        at com.androidy.listactivity.NameListActivity$GetNameData.doInBackground(NameListActivity.java:142)
        at    com.androidy.listactivity.NameListActivity$GetNameData.doInBackground(NameListActivity.java:121)
```

Answer (score 0):

in this snippet,

```
 int contentLength = connection.getContentLength();
 char[] charArray = new char[contentLength];
 reader.read(charArray);
 String responseData = new String(charArray);
```

you are using the return value of content length, to allocate a byte array, and in your case it is returning -1, causing the exception. A possible fix:

```
 StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
 byte[] array = new byte[8092];
 int read = 0;

 while ((read = inputStream.read(array)) != -1) {
       builder.append(new String(array, 0, read));
 }

jsonResponse = new JSONArray(builder.toString());
```

Comment: StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                    byte[] array = new byte[8092];
                    int read = 0;

                    while ((read = is.read(array)) != -1) {
                        builder.append(new String(array, 0, read));
                    }

                    jsonResponse = new JSONArray(builder.toString());

Comment: the "is." is giving me a problem now... it says Cannot resolve symbol is

Comment: `is` it is the `InputStream`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28400522/my-simple-adapter-wont-populate-my-listview     sorry to bug you but i am new and have been working on this for days... do you see anything wrong with my code?